# Create user DateTime class

Tags: c#

I have to create my own DateTime class with fields seconds,minutes,hours,days,months and years. I've had a problem with realization method `void AddDays(int N)`,which adds N days(N may be negative). I do not understand what idea should lie in this function to add days worked correctly. I was trying to understand how the system class works, but for now it's difficult for me.

```
public TimeDate(int second, int minute, int hour,
            int day, int month, int year)
        {
            _second = second;
            _minute = minute;
            _hour = hour;
            _day = day;
            _month = month;
            _year = year;
        }
        private long _second;
        private long _minute;
        private long _hour;
        private long _day;
        private long _month;
        private long _year;
        private long[] dayYear = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
        private long[] dayYearLeap ={0,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

        private bool isLeap()
        {
            if (_year % 4 == 0)
            {
                if (_year % 100 == 0)
                {
                    if (_year % 400 == 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
public void AddDays(int N)
        {
            long N_in_second = N * 60*60*24;
            long second_now = _second + _minute * 60 + _hour * 60 * 60 + _day * 60 * 60 * 24;
            if (isLeap())
            {
                second_now +=  _month*3600*24*dayYearLeap[_month]+
                              _year * 60 * 60 * 24 * dayYearLeap[_month] * 12;
            }
            else
            {
                second_now += _month * 3600 * 24 * dayYear[_month] +
                              _year * 60 * 60 * 24 * dayYear[_month] * 12;
            }

            second_now += N_in_second;
            _year = second_now / (60*60*24*12*dayYear[_month]);
            second_now -= 60 * 60 * 24 * 12 * dayYear[_month];
            _month = second_now / (60 * 60 * 24 * dayYear[_month]) % 12;
            if (_month == 0) _month = 12;
            second_now -= (60 * 60 * 24 * dayYear[_month]);
            _day = second_now / (60 * 60 * 24) % dayYear[_month];
            second_now -= (60 * 60 * 24);
            _hour = second_now / (60 * 60) % 24;
            second_now -= (60 * 60);
            _minute = second_now / 60 % 60;
            second_now -= 60;
            _second = second_now % 60;
        }
```

in main function I wrote `TimeDate date = new TimeDate(34,27,13,28,2,2019); date.AddDays(5);` output was: `Second: 34, Minute: 27, Hour: 13, Day: 12, Month: 3,Year: 2019`, but it's extra 7 days. Where did I go wrong? if the year becomes a leap year after the summation, how can I catch this?

Comment: Look at the source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,df6b1eba7461813b

Comment: You have stated a problem but you do not appear to have actually asked a question

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain what exactly the problem you're facing is. "difficult to understand" doesn't really doesn't give us a lot to go on. Try to provide a [mre] to show us what you've tried.

Comment: What happens when you add 1 day? Does it work?

Comment: @tytam, output: Second: 34, Minute: 27, Hour: 13, Day: 8, Month: 3,Year: 2019. The same 7 extra days

Comment: @tytam, But if I use negative number, it works correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public void AddDays(int N)
        {
            if (N >= 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                {
                    _day++;
                    if (isLeap())
                    {
                        if (_day > dayYearLeap[_month])
                        {
                            _day = 1;
                            _month++;
                            if (_month > 12)
                            {
                                _year++;
                                _month = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (_day > dayYear[_month])
                        {
                            _day = 1;
                            _month++;
                            if (_month > 12)
                            {
                                _year++;
                                _month = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Math.Abs(N); i++)
                {
                    _day--;

                    if (_day == 0)
                    {
                        _month--;
                        if (isLeap())
                        {
                            if (_month < 1)
                            {
                                _year--;
                                _month = 12;
                            }

                            _day = dayYearLeap[_month];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (_month < 1)
                            {
                                _year--;
                                _month = 12;
                            }

                            _day = dayYear[_month];
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```